# Why my program have errors with memory leak checking?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

When I use this

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./Main
```

I have about 185236 errors. It said that:

> xx bytes in x blocks are possibly lost in loss record xxxx of xxxx

Here's my code:

```
Node InsertString(Head head, Node tree, char* data) {
    if (tree == NULL) {
        tree = malloc(sizeof (struct TreeNode)); //Error

        if (tree == NULL) {
            printf("Out of Space!\n");
        } else {
             tree->theData = malloc(sizeof (char) * strlen(data));//Error
            strcpy(tree->theData, data);
        }
    } else {
            if (strcmp(data, tree->theData) < 0) {
                tree->Left = InsertString(head, tree->Left, data); //Error
            } else {
                if (strcmp(data, tree->theData) > 0) {
                    tree->Right = InsertString(head, tree->Right, data);//Error
                }
            }
        } 

    }
    return tree;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you `free` the data?

Comment: Do you think where should i free the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you ever call `free` to deallocate the memory you are allocating with `malloc`?

If not, well, then you're leaking all that memory.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying me, Can you explain to me why we have to malloc for a memory space to store data and then we free it?

Comment: @Tuan:  It would behoove you to obtain [a good beginner C book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  I cannot sufficiently explain the C memory model and best practices for dynamic allocation in C in the short space available for this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use a tool called valgrind. It will tell you of such memory leaks.

Comment: Did you read the question?  The fifth word in the question is "valgrind".